# Error module "QtQuick.Dialogs" is not installed

Tags: qt, qml

I've got the following error upon trying to add QtQuick.Dialogs 1.(0/1/2) to my project:

```
qrc:/qml/main.qml:4 module "QtQuick.Dialogs" is not installed
```

Now here is the thing, if I create a completely new app (standard empty QtQuick application) and add this line and the file dialog example from QML FileDialog documentation, then there is no problem.

Any ideas on what the problem might be?

Answer (score 5):

Solved it!! It turns out that the problem was that I had used windeployqt on the output folder. This conflicted with adding new qtquick components. The solution was to delete everything in the output folder and generate a clean compiled and it worked. In case it helps anyone else.

Comment: OMG! I lost 1 hour on this. Thanks!

Comment: No problem! Glad it could help!